# Is it possible to convert Bootstrap css components to Tailwind css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css

I'm using **Tailwind CSS** library in my web project. I want to convert all **Bootstrap CSS** components and use them in my web project. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define some Bootstrap components as custom and use them in the Tailwind project. The downside here is to distinguish between [common class styles](https://github.com/andreaseriksson/bootstrap-tailwind-components) and globally defined class styles used by components defined in the Tailwind library and the Bootstrap library. In this case, if you change the class names of the Bootstrap component you want to add externally to the project, there will be no conflict. You can check [this demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ9XK55B9oo) for easier discovery.

One way to manually add some components is to create a new bootstrap project and open DevTools in the browser to explore the styles of [reverse engineered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001686/reverse-engineering-a-bootstrap-menubar) elements from the Styles panel on the Element tab.

Comment: Hi @Sercen - Just one clarification. As of now, my project is in **React + Bootstrap** which I want to convert to **React + Tailwind**. Without impacting any features or functionalities?

Comment: The best way is to reverse engineer and update the names of classes that might conflict. I think if you have such a need, don't confuse the two libraries. Take care of your needs by writing CSS code yourself. Otherwise you'll have to deal with converting libraries when you need to deal with the project. A little advice.